# DynamoDB NullPointerException Error on save

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-dynamodb

Im trying to save info to DynamoDB but im currently getting the error `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` when using "save" on the `AccountHelper` class.

I followed the starter guide found on Github; https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb

Here is my Model Class;

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Users")
public class User {

  //  @Id
    private String _id;
    private String bloodGroup;
    private String firstName; // DO NOT change this, needs to stay firstName
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String addressline;
    private String postcode;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public User() {}

    // More Constructors, Getters & Setters
```

DynamoDB Config Class;

```
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {DynamoDBRepo.class})})
@Configuration
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    public AWSCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialsProvider() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(amazonAWSCredentials());
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig() {
        return DynamoDBMapperConfig.DEFAULT;
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB, DynamoDBMapperConfig config) {
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB, config);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(amazonAWSCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    }
}
```

Here is the method/class where i am getting the error;

```
    @Service
    public class AccountHelper {

    private DynamoDBRepo dynamoDBRepo;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public User create(String bloodGroup, String firstname, String surname, String email, String password, String addressline, String postcode) {
        // Getting the error here
        return dynamoDBRepo.save(new User(bloodGroup, firstname, surname, email, bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password), addressline, postcode)); 

    }

    // More methods below that i am not adding to keep this question to a minimum.
```

Here is my controller;

```
@Controller
@Component
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountHelper Service_functions;

    @ResponseBody // Works
    @PostMapping(value = "/create/{bloodGroup}/{firstname}/{surname}/{email}/{password}/{addressline}/{postcode}")
    public String create( @PathVariable String bloodGroup , @PathVariable  String firstname, @PathVariable  String surname, @PathVariable  String email, @PathVariable  String password, @PathVariable  String addressline, @PathVariable  String postcode){
        User CreateUser = Service_functions.create(bloodGroup, firstname,  surname,  email,  password,  addressline,  postcode);
        System.out.println("this is working");
        return CreateUser.toString();
    }
```

account properties;

```
spring.application.name=account-service
server.port=8020
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8001/eureka/
amazon.aws.accesskey="" // i removed the keys
amazon.aws.secretkey=""
```

Any Suggestions/Help would be greatly on where i am going wrong.

Comment: You should maybe attach the whole Stacktrace. Maybe that can lead you to where the NullPointerException is coming from.

Comment: @Pampy I believe the error i am recieving is becuase i do not have `@Autowire`, but when i do add it, i get an error saying that it cannot find `com.bdonor.accountservice.Repository.DynamoDBRepo`

Comment: did you fix this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you need to fix here based on your details provided.

- Add `@Autowired` annotation on your `dynamoDBRepo` variable so that it can be recognised as spring managed bean.
- Based on your comment

> i.e. error saying that it cannot find
>   com.bdonor.accountservice.Repository.DynamoDBRepo

You need to include `com.bdonor.accountservice.Repository` package as JPA repository package and enable jpa repository scan in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, adding `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.bdonor.accountservice.Repository")` gave the error  `Field dynamoDBRepo in com.bdonor.accountservice.Models.AccountHelper required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.` which i am currently trying to debug

Comment: @stackoverflown you have lot of required configuration missing. All these are incremental issues after solving your actual issue you posted in the question. However all these issues can not be addressed in single question. If you find the answer to your original question satisfied than do accept the answer.

Comment: Can you tell me some of the configurations that i am missing?